# How to replace two strings at once avoiding repeating replacement in Python?

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to replace two strings using python in a text like:
`text="This is a rhopialg, not a rhopi"`
I want to exactly replace `"rhopialg"` by `"myrhopialg"`, replace `"rhopi"` by `"myrhopi"`

If I use `text.replace('rhopialg' , 'myrhopialg').replace('rhopi','myrhopi')`, the result is
`"This is a mymyrhopialg, not a myrhopi."`, The first word replaced two times, not correct.

The expected result after replace is: "This is a myrhopialg, not a myrhopi"

How to achieve this ensuring replace only once?

Comment: Replace each string with some character that doesn't otherwise appear in your text (Unicode gives you *lots* of possibilities), and then replace those characters with the final strings.  The intermediate value might look like `This is a ①, not a ②`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex:

```
import re

text = "This is a rhopialg, not a rhopi"

out = re.sub('rhopialg|rhopi' , 'myrhopi', text)
```

Or, to restrict to full words:

```
out = re.sub(r'\b(rhopialg|rhopi)\b' , 'myrhopi', text)
```

To compress the regex, since part of the string is common:

```
out = re.sub(r'\brhopi(?:alg)?\b' , 'myrhopi', text)
```

Output: `'This is a myrhopi, not a myrhopi'`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  If I want to replace "rhopialg" by "myrhopialg", "rhopi" by "myrhopi",  How to achieve this- "This is a myrhopialg, not a myrhopi"?

Comment: Since you have the same prefix to add, you could use `re.sub(r'(rhopi(?:alg)?)' , r'my\1', text)`. For a fully flexible way, use a dictionary of replacements.

Comment: I tried this: d = {"rhopialg": "myrhopialg", "rhopi": "myrhopi"}
re.sub("|".join(d), lambda x: d[x.group(0)], text),  but this is not right, what's wrong?

Comment: Exactly that should work, make sure to place the longest words first in the dictionary, I'd just use `"|".join(map(re.escape, d))` just in case your target words could contains special regex characters (not needed if only letters)

Comment: Can you explain how this "*is not right*"? Works fine with the example

Comment: d = {"rhopialg": "myrhopialg", "rhopi": "myrhopi"} this really leads to "This is a myrhopialg, not a myrhopi".  But if I use d = {"rhopialg": "myrhopi", "rhopi": "myrhopi"}, I do not get "This is a myrhopi, not a myrhopi"，  can we unify this two cases?

Comment: I can't reproduce: `d = {"rhopialg": "myrhopi", "rhopi": "myrhopi"} ; re.sub("|".join(map(re.escape, d)), lambda x: d[x.group(0)], text)` works as expected

Comment: Yes. Using d = {"rhopialg": "myrhopi", "rhopi": "myrhopi"} , how to get "This is a myrhopi, not a myrhopi"?

Comment: Well it **does** give `'This is a myrhopi, not a myrhopi'`

Comment: What I need is "rhopialg" replaced by "text1",  "rhopi" replaced by "text2", every word only replace once avoiding repeated replacement.

Comment: No.  d = {"rhopialg": "myrhopi", "rhopi": "myrhopi"} ; re.sub("|".join(map(re.escape, d)), lambda x: d[x.group(0)], text)  gives "This is a myrhopialg, not a myrhopi"

Comment: Sorry, but [not for me](https://tio.run/##TY7BCoMwEETv@YplTwkEKfQm9C96Kz3EJmiKyS4xgmL77WlEhMJc5s0wDK95oHgtxQemlCE5IbJbMtwA74OfoMpAGoi9GXsNkfLpUdja2vAMsQUM6xFpOPA/@wqa993kmmnuJH6weZOPMhiWlbnpZdhpsEppGE3orIGlBftYmj7RzPKinhr2b0pw8jHLOqdEKT8)

Comment: There is a more "alg" in the first replacement.

Comment: It seems this difference is caused by python version. In python3, there is no alg.